# Sonarlint "refactor redunant await on non promise" code hint... but function does return a promise

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, promise, jsdoc, sonarlint

I'm writing a small script and for readability of the calling method (main) I decided to wrap fetches with a bunch of headers into their own methods.

```
async function main(){
...
   let res = get_fromSpecificFetch();
...
}

async function get_fromSpecificFetch() {
    try {
        return fetch("https://www.website.com/apiendpoint", {
            "headers": {
                "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"90\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"90\"",
                "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
                "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
            },
            "referrer": "https://www.website.com/",
            "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
            "body": null,
            "method": "GET",
            "mode": "cors"
        })
    } catch {
        throw new Error("launch");
    }
}
```

Sonarlint highlights my code and says:
"Refactor this redundant await on a non-promise".

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ye5Tx8b.png]

...but this does return a promise. If I don't await this, then my promise will still be pending. I dont want to disable this rule (because it is useful when it's correct), but in this case it is wrong.

I understand I'm not using typescript, so how does solarlint even know the return type?
Would defining the return type with something like JsDoc fix this?

Maybe there is a better way to organize my code?

(I can't define this fetch wrapper once and pass different url/headers objects because sometimes there will be parsing logic inside my fetch wrapper, but this wouldnt solve my issue anyway)

Comment: What happens if you remove `async` from `get_fromSpecificFetch`, remove the `try/catch` blocks from inside it, and either leave out the `catch` block altogether or convert it to a `.catch()` method call on the `fetch` promise?

Comment: I ended up putting the fetches in different files (better for organization anyway), imported them, and the hint goes away

Comment: This bug is monitored in the following issue https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/2636